# Can create objects using Amplify GraphQL but deleting the same object is unauthorized - using Cognito User Pools for Auth

Tags: swift, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Title.

I am able to create a Like to a Post in my app, but whenever I try to delete the app, I get an unauthorized error:

```
Amplify.GraphQLError(message: "Not Authorized to access deleteLike on type Mutation", locations: Optional([Amplify.GraphQLError.Location(line: 2, column: 3)]), path: Optional([Amplify.JSONValue.string("deleteLike")])
```

Here is my schema if this helps:

```
type Post @model 
  @auth(rules: [
    {allow: owner, ownerField:"owner", provider: userPools, operations:[read, create, delete]}
    {allow: private, provider: userPools, operations:[read]}
  ])
{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  type: String @index(name: "postsByDate", queryField: "postsByDate", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  content: String!
  owner: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  likes: [Like] @hasMany(indexName: "likesByPost", fields: ["id"])
}

type Like @model 
  @auth(rules: [
    {allow: owner, ownerField:"user", provider: userPools, operations: [read, create, delete]}
    {allow: private, provider: userPools, operations:[read]}
  ])
{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  postID: ID! @index(name: "likesByPost", queryField: "likesByPost", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  post: Post! @belongsTo(fields: ["postID"])
  user: String @index(name: "likesByUser", queryField: "likesByUser", sortKeyFields: ["postID"])
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

And here is where I delete the like:

```swift
    private func removeLikeFromPost(post: Post, userID: String) async {
        let like = await getLikeFromPost(post: post, userID: userID) // this gives me a like without error
        do {
            let result = try await Amplify.API.mutate(request: .delete(like)) // error here
            switch result {
            case .success(let like):
                print("INFO successfully deleted like: \(like)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("ERROR got failed result with \(error)")
            }
        } catch let error as APIError {
            print("ERROR failed to delete a like: ", error)
        } catch {
            print("ERROR unexpected error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```